# Preferably than 5 days when the user has set up

Tags: c#, datetime

That's the way I'm doing so that those customers who have not bought membership should send out newsletters.

Right now it takes hold of everyone.

But I would only have had those who have been set up for the last 5 days.

```
var FiveDays = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);//There must have been 5 days

var userlist = db.Users.Where(i => i.CreateDateTime.Day <= FiveDays.Day &&
 i.CreateDateTime.Month <= FiveDays.Month &&
 i.CreateDateTime.Year <= FiveDays.Year &&
 i.CustomerID == null).ToList();
```

So what it's supposed to do is take it all in the 5 days and the rest it's not allowed to be left alone.

As it seems, it should only take one from the database.

Comment: why not just `i.CreatedDateTime <=FiveDays`?

Comment: Why not just `i.CreateDateTime <= FiveDays`?

Comment: @DavidG: I suppose it was an obvious comment. ;-)

Comment: @Chris It would appear so (though I missed the `=` initially)

Comment: Yea okay, Thanks Chris and DavidG

Answer (score 1):

...and the problem is? If comparison is the problem, then I would advise using CompareTo method. This kind of comparison you are using is wrong, because it wouldn't accept the date from previous year having greater value of Day